# How to check variable value in html

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make an easy login page in html and JavaScript but the if statement always returns false

```
<html>

    <style>
        .enterUsername{
            margin-top: 350px;
            margin-left: 710px;
        }
        .enterPassword{
            margin-left: 710px;
        }
        #submitButton{
            margin-left: 760px;
        }
        #wrongPsswdText{
            margin-left: 720px;
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
    const username = document.getElementById("inputUser");
    const password = document.getElementById("inputPsswd");

    function tryAgainText(){
        var text = document.getElementById("wrongPsswdText");
        text.style.display = "block";
    }
    function Login(){
      if(username == "admin" && password == "1234"){
          window.location.replace("mainpage.html");
         
     }
     else{
           tryAgainText();
           
        }
    }
    </script>
    <body>
        <div>
             <input class="enterUsername" type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username" id="inputUser" required><br><br>
             <input class="enterPassword" type="text" placeholder="Password" name="password" id="inputPsswd" required><br><br>
             <p id="wrongPsswdText">Wrong password, try again.</p>
             <input id="submitButton" onclick="Login()" type="submit" value="Login" >
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

What can I do so it will redirect me to mainpage.html when I set the username and password to admin and 1234?

Comment: Question for you to think about: What prevents me from directly navigating to mainpage.html ?

Comment: You need to get the value of elements, you don't want to check the elements themselves
`username.value === "admin" && password.value === "1234"`

Comment: Note that this should be seen as a toy only; it is very insecure. Anyone can view the source code of the page and see the password.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Element.value](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_text_value.asp)

```
<html>

    <style>
    
    </style>
    <body>
        <div>
             <input class="enterUsername" type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username" id="inputUser" required><br><br>
             <input class="enterPassword" type="text" placeholder="Password" name="password" id="inputPsswd" required><br><br>
             <p id="wrongPsswdText">Wrong password, try again.</p>
             <input id="submitButton" onclick="Login()" type="submit" value="Login" >
        </div>
          <script>
// You Need to get Value from the input field So You need to Use .value 


    function tryAgainText(){
        var text = document.getElementById("wrongPsswdText");
        text.style.display = "block";
    }
    function Login(){
    const username = document.getElementById("inputUser").value;
    const password = document.getElementById("inputPsswd").value;
    console.log(username == "admin" , username , password == "1234")
      if(username == "admin" && password == "1234"){
         console.log("Yes ")
         
     }
     else{
           tryAgainText();
           
        }
    }
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This fixes only half the issue. Right now, this is still trying to read the field values, right when this code runs - the user did not even have a chance to input something into those fields yet! Reading the values needs to happen inside the `Login` function, so that it always uses the _current_ field values at this point.

Comment: Already tried .value and didn't work, but I'm gonna try CBroe's method. Thanks.

Comment: @Gigel I have edited Code HAve a look now it works

Answer (score 0):

you need to put JavaScript code at the end of the body
and put `value` property in `username` and `password`

`const username = document.getElementById("inputUser").value;`

`const password = document.getElementById("inputPsswd").value;`

```
<html>

    <body>
        <div>
             <input class="enterUsername" type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username" id="inputUser" required><br><br>
             <input class="enterPassword" type="text" placeholder="Password" name="password" id="inputPsswd" required><br><br>
             <p id="wrongPsswdText">Wrong password, try again.</p>
             <input id="submitButton" onclick="Login()" type="submit" value="Login" >
        </div>
 <script>
    const username = document.getElementById("inputUser").value;
    const password = document.getElementById("inputPsswd").value;

    function tryAgainText(){
        var text = document.getElementById("wrongPsswdText");
        text.style.display = "block";
    }
    function Login(){
      if(username == "admin" && password == "1234"){
          window.location.replace("mainpage.html");
         
     }
     else{
           tryAgainText();
           
        }
    }
</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You almost had it! The only change is that instead of comparing the `HTMLInputElement` to a string you do compare its value!

`username.value == "admin" && password.value == "1234"`

```js
const username = document.getElementById("inputUser");
const password = document.getElementById("inputPsswd");
const text = document.getElementById("wrongPsswdText");

function tryAgainText() {
  text.style.display = "block";
}

function Login() {
  if (username.value == "admin" && password.value == "1234") {
    console.log("Navigate to: mainpage.html");
  } else {
    tryAgainText();
  }
}
```

```css
#wrongPsswdText {
  display: none;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input class="enterUsername" type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username" id="inputUser" required><br><br>
  <input class="enterPassword" type="text" placeholder="Password" name="password" id="inputPsswd" required><br><br>
  <p id="wrongPsswdText">Wrong password, try again.</p>
  <input id="submitButton" onclick="Login()" type="submit" value="Login">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
    .enterUsername{
        margin-top: 350px;
        margin-left: 710px;
    }
    .enterPassword{
        margin-left: 710px;
    }
    #submitButton{
        margin-left: 760px;
    }
    #wrongPsswdText{
        margin-left: 720px;
        display: none;
    }
</style>
<script>
var username = document.getElementById("inputUser");
var password = document.getElementById("inputPsswd");

function tryAgainText(){
    var text = document.getElementById("wrongPsswdText");
    text.style.display = "block";
}
function Login(){
  if(username.value == "admin" && password.value == "1234"){
      window.location.replace("mainpage.html");
     
 }
 else{
       tryAgainText();
       
    }
}
</script>
<body>
    <div>
         <input class="enterUsername" type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username" id="inputUser" required><br><br>
         <input class="enterPassword" type="text" placeholder="Password" name="password" id="inputPsswd" required><br><br>
         <p id="wrongPsswdText">Wrong password, try again.</p>
         <input id="submitButton" onclick="Login()" type="submit" value="Login" >
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: since you are defining the elements outside the block scope, better to go with var!, then the elements will be accessible as global variables

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to use the `script` tag at the final of the `body` tag

(the content of your HTML file) is executed sequentially, and until you accept or close any javascript dialog (alert, prompt or confirm) the browser will not continue executing the rest.

This is the reason why on some websites, the JS files are put at the end before the closing Body tag so that the user can see the content while the javascript files are loaded below.

2. To obtain the value of your input tag need to use `document.getElementById('exampleID').value` it will return the value of the placeholder input.

```
<style>
    .enterUsername{
        margin-top: 350px;
        margin-left: 710px;
    }
    .enterPassword{
        margin-left: 710px;
    }
    #submitButton{
        margin-left: 760px;
    }
    #wrongPsswdText{
        margin-left: 720px;
        display: none;
    }
</style>

<body>
    <div>
         <input class="enterUsername" type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username" id="inputUser" required><br><br>
         <input class="enterPassword" type="text" placeholder="Password" name="password" id="inputPsswd" required><br><br>
         <p id="wrongPsswdText">Wrong password, try again.</p>
         <input id="submitButton" onclick="Login()" type="submit" value="Login" >
    </div>
    <script>
        const username = document.getElementById('inputUser');
        console.log(" ~ file: index.html ~ line 29 ~ username", username)
        const password = document.getElementById("inputPsswd");
        console.log(" ~ file: index.html ~ line 31 ~ password", password)
        
    
        function tryAgainText(){
            var text = document.getElementById("wrongPsswdText");
            text.style.display = "block";
        }
        function Login(){
          if(username.value == "admin" && password.value == "1234"){
              window.location.replace("mainpage.html");
         }
         else{
               tryAgainText();
               
            }
        }
        </script>
</body>
```